# Attaching a view to a content type that takes the content type's taxonomy terms as arguments

Tags: views

What I am trying to do is create a content type with a taxonomy vocabulary field. When creating the content type and selecting one or more of the terms, I would like the content type with an attached view to render the node with a list of nodes (ex: teaser views) that share share the content type's selected taxonomy terms.

In the past I have used Insert Views and listed the taxonomy terms. I would like a more elegant solution so a user can just use a selection list or term radio buttons.

How would I go about attaching a view and passing the taxonomy terms of the content type to the "attached" view?

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Rich

Comment: So you mean when creating the node, when you select any taxonomy term, all the nodes with the same taxonomy term should be displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to the template, a variable which contains the second view value

```
function mymodule_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  list($id, $rev, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($type, $entity);
  switch ($bundle){
    case 'customtype':
      if( $view_mode == 'teaser' ){
        $entity->test['test'] = array(
          '#markup' => views_embed_view( 'view_2', 'default', $entity->field_custom['und'][0]['value'] ),
        );
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Then, in your theme, a node--customtype.tpl.php, you can render the variable:

```
print render($test);
```